# How do I get a TOC sidebar of my current buffer?

Tags: text-editing, markdown

I would like to write in markdown mode for example and then have a sidebar that shows me a table of contents of the buffer I am currently in.

Comment: While not a sidebar, the `imenu` library works with `org-mode` and `markdown-mode` among others -- it provides a nice table of contents in the menubar or a mouse-pop-up-menu (e.g., right-click-context-menu, which is especially nice if the menubar is hidden by choice).  `imenu` can be activated for supported modes by adding `(imenu-add-menubar-index)` to the major-mode hook.  [FYI:  speedbar taps into the functionality of imenu and/or etags.]

Answer (score 3):

You can get that, more or less, with `M-x speedbar`.  It displays the files in the current directory, and lets you expand the files to see a table of contents.  (For source code, it shows a list of functions.)

However, you need to tell Speedbar to show contents for Markdown files, by customizing `speedbar-supported-extension-expressions` and adding the file extension you use for Markdown files.

By default, Speedbar hides files not matching `speedbar-supported-extension-expressions` entirely.  You can set `speedbar-show-unknown-files` to `t` to make it show them in the list, even though it doesn't display an outline for them.

Comment: The original poster is also apparently fond of `org-mode` [based on other recent threads], and said poster may be interested to know that speedbar can create a table of contents for `org-mode` files by adding the `org-mode` file extensions to `speedbar-supported-extension-expressions`.  The original poster is not fond of speedbar frames, however, it is possible to modify the source code of speedbar to entirely remove the frame sutff -- unfortunately, that requires semi-advanced `elisp` skills.  `sr-speedbar` advices too many functions for my taste, but that is one method of reducing frames.

Comment: Yes I ended up using orgmode.

Comment: @lawlist Great idea, let me know if you wind up writing code to remove frames from speedbar.